# ReactJS need help finding cause of Maximum Depth Exceeded error

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to find the root cause of why react is exceeding the depth limit in the render function.

The error is occurring where it is attempting to append a new element to the results state array.

this.setState({results: [...this.state.results,{examBoard, falsePos, tumorDetections}] });

It must be something with the way I update the array or something simple elsewhere.

```
render() {

let grid = null;
let results = null;
let resultsGrid = null;
...


if (this.state.examComplete == false) {
   ... no errors were triggered here before adding the else below.      
}
else {
  let examBoard = this.board;
  let falsePos = this.state.falsePositives;
  let tumorDetections = this.state.tumorsConfig;

  this.setState({results: [...this.state.results,{examBoard, falsePos, tumorDetections}] });

  this.setState({examAttempts: this.state.examAttempts + 1});

  restart = <button onClick={this.restartExam} style={{ margin: '10px', fontSize: '125%' }}>Restart the exam</button>

  resultsGrid =
    <div className={styles.inline}>
      {this.state.results.map(result => (
        <ResultsGrid palpatedCells={result.examBoard} falsePositives={result.falsePos} tumors={result.tumorDetections} />
      ))}
    </div>

}

return (
  <div>
    <h3>Exam Grid</h3>
    <br />
    {end}
    {restart}
    {detectionOutput}
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {grid}
    </div>
    <div>
      {resultsGrid} {data}
    </div>

  </div>
);
```

}
}

Comment: `setState()` triggers re-rendering in react, so calling it in `render()` is a big red flag. I would try refactoring your logic to make sure you dont have a case of infinite render -> setState -> render -> setState...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks jlau, removing the logic from render solved it. Dumb mistake.